# Framework7 v5 best way to include custom js files

Tags: cordova, webpack, html-framework-7

Hi just recently installed Framework7 v5 with webpack and cordova. What is the best way to include custom JS files so webpack will bundle them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your source directory (src/js) you can add lib directory and put any js file like this:

```
import * as customJs from 'lib/customJs';
```

Example from real project:

```
import * as formsHelper   from './helpers/formsHelper';
```

webpack will get it automatically and bundle it since theres loader git all js file inside src.